# iPhone, label at end of compound statement

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to add a label I think thats what they are called...

[image]

.. just like I've done several times before to exit a function without processing some code and I'm getting the error 'label at end of compound statement' why ? what do i need to do instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is this --->DontPutToDBOrClose:

compiler thinks its a goto label you're defining.

Comment: remember how you were used to define labels like this to jump to code snippets in c....

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a label hanging by itself at the end of the method--it has to have at least one valid statement following it. If you need to skip over some code and return early, just use `return`. You can use as many `return` statements as you need.